# How to check language being used on a device?

Tags: java, android

I have android project as quiz app , I need to run some code if user system lang is English , and another code if user system lang Arabic or other , how can I do that. I mean , if the lang eng run sound right answer , and if the lang is other run another sound of different lang.

```
public void checkAnswer(View view) {
    Button answerBtn = (Button) findViewById(view.getId());
    String btnText = answerBtn.getText().toString();
    String alerTitle;

    if (btnText.equals(rightAnswer)) {
        alertTitle=(getString(R.string.rightAnswer));
        rightAnswerCount++;
        score.setText(String.valueOf(rightAnswerCount));
        answerBtn.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.c));
        mpright = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.right_ans);
        mpright.start();
        Animation anm = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.abc_popup_exit);
        answerBtn.startAnimation(anm);
    } else {
        alertTitle =getString(R.string.wrongAnswer);
        wrongAnswerCount++;
        wrong.setText(String.valueOf(wrongAnswerCount));
        //  wrongBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        answerBtn.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.d));
        mpwrong = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.wronge_ans);
        mpwrong.start();
        Animation anm = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.abc_tooltip_enter);
        answerBtn.startAnimation(anm);
    }
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(alertTitle);
    builder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface p1, int p2) {
                if (quizCount == Quiz_Count) {
                    Intent result = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ResultActivity.class);
                    result.putExtra("Right_Answer_Count", rightAnswerCount);
                    startActivity(result);
                } else {
                    quizCount++;
                    ShowNextQuiz();
                }
            }
        });
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.show();
```

Comment: also related [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26450589/how-to-check-for-a-device-language-in-android)

Comment: No no, i mean i need make if statement , ie, if default language is english run the sound file of english , and if the the other language run another sound file of different language.

Comment: You can...use an if statement with the value in that link.

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
if( Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equalsIgnoreCase("en")) {
           // English
}else{
        //other
}
```